# ¿cómo ver el código HTML de una plantilla de bootstrap?

Tags: html, bootstrap

buena tarde, disculpen muchachos, soy algo nuevo en la programación y quería preguntarles cómo puedo ver el codigo html de una plantilla de bootstrap, por ejemplo hay un tema cuyo nombre es simplex... pero al darle inspeccionar, aparece es el codigo HTML de toda la página, pues con códigos los cuales no los necesitaria, realmente.

¡ Agradezco mucho su ayuda !

Comment: Cual es tu duda? Explica de manera mejor tu pregunta

Comment: Ya estas viendo el código html, para ver completamente toda la plantilla tienes que descargarla y ver no solo el código html si no tambien css y javascript es eso lo que tambien te interesara para poder utilizarla...

Comment: exacto la pregunta se podría reducir a cómo puedo descargar la plantilla simplex de bootstrap, agradecería mucho tu ayuda !

Answer (score 1):

primeramente concordamos en que bootstrap es un conjunto de funciones y estilos aplicadas a "objetos" html especificos.  Entonces, deduzco que tu deseas ver el código de bootstrap que activa cierto efecto, ya sea para comprender como funciona o intentar hacer tu propia versión.  En fin, si hablamos de un tema bootstrap, como mencionas "simplex" solo tienes que ir a https://bootswatch.com/simplex/ en donde encontraras todos los componentes que la plantilla afecta y lo más importante en la esquina "superior derecha" de cada objeto veras un icono <> que cuando das click te muestra precisamente el codigo html que se uso.  Espero te sirva esta info!!!

Comment: muchas gracias por su ayuda,todo se podría reducir a que el problema principal es que no logro descargar la plantilla simplex, para mi proyecto... y de nuevo muchas gracias por su tiempo y ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Para que este problema no te ocurra debes ver un poco los videos sobre como usar bootstrap. en youtube hay muchos. es muy sencillo. solo debes saber como activar sus funciones. luego si quieres usar themes de bootstrap como paper simplex o yeti que son muy vistosos entra en su pagina oficial en https://bootswatch.com o descarga los temas de bootswatch en github. que son todos y bienen mejor explicados. saludos

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda !! \o/